# Google Sheets: remove specific characters from string except decimal

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi I have a column of messy data within Google Sheets I'm trying to clean up and remove any non-numeric characters except decimals.

I'm having issues with the expression syntax within REGEXREPLACE (this works to remove the brackets/ quotes/ colon but also removes decimals, I want the decimals to remain):

=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\D+", ""))

```
{"result":[[1482710400
69294586954.95]
[1513209600
70212683668.01]
[1513296000
71293570461.83]
[1513382400
72432097963.87]
[1513468800
74422755261.42]
[1513555200
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just tested the following and have confirmed that it works

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^0-9.]+", "")
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks so much for the quick reply.